# ASP.NET ContentPlaceHolder - How to Register Data within MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, image, contentplaceholder

I have 2 MasterPages (A main MasterPage and Simple MasterPage) I use only the Simple one with my other pages. Here part of my program:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="description">
    <br />
    Name : <asp:TextBox ID="TextName" Text="" runat="server" />
    Image :<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="20px" />

...</div></asp:Content>
```

How to register data (ex. name) and an image in a database?

I tried with:

```
name = Request.Form["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMainContent$TextName"];
name = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$TextName"];   
img = ???
```

But I only saw a space with `NULL` in the database.

Comment: What do you mean "register data"?

Comment: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Comment: to save info in a database